# How to pass cookie to NSUrlSession?

Tags: ios, xamarin, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

For iOS, I have written a custom delegate and implementation of `NSUrlSession`. It is working fine for Http urls. But when I try to download image resources from a HTTPS source that has been authenticated and which require a Cookie to be passed, the download fails with a `NSUrlErrorCode` -1013 or -1002.

```
 NSMutableUrlRequest req = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(uri.ToString()));
 req.Headers = dictHeaders;//
 NSUrlSessionDownloadTask newTask = session.CreateDownloadTask(req);
 activeDownloads.Add(newTask);
 newTask.Resume();
```

So in the `NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate` I have implemented the `DidReceiveChallenge` method but am not passing anything there currently because I want to pass the cookie from my initial login as above.

`NSUrlSession` uses shared session for the complete app but my initial login API is done using `RestSharp.RestClient` which fetches the cookie that I can use throughout the app.

So my question is how do I pass the cookie to `NSUrlSession` ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all work with cookies goes through `NSHTTPCookieStorage` class https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html. You can use `cookieAcceptPolicy` to configure how cookies are used in your application and even manually add/remove cookies if needed.

NSURLSession will take cookie from NSHTTPCookieStorage.

Comment: Yes that is what the document says and was the first thing I tried, but can we convert string (header value) to a NSHTTPCookieStorage object.

Comment: You need to fill in all the cookie fields, at least, domain/name/value. WHat exactly string do you need to convert?